# AppleScript app started prompting to run or quit. How can I disable this?

Tags: applications, applescript, permission, textmate, command-line

I'm not entirely sure why this has started happening since this is completely new behaviour and I haven't done any system updates but I have a nice little toolbar app for my Snow Leopard Finder.app that opens the existing folder/or files in TextMate.

It used to simply bring up TextMate with the chosen content but since today it instead gives me a prompt asking me to run or quit the script.

Here is what the popup looks like:
[image: Script popup]

Now… this app/script isn't new, I trust the script and I don't want this popup everytime I use it.

So 2 questions:

1. How do I disable this annoying prompt?
2. Why am I all of a sudden getting it when yesterday everything was working fine?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

For reference the script in question is this one: [OpenInTextMate](http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/10/open-in-textmate-from-leopard-finder)
However the [MateDot.app](http://manas.tungare.name/software/finder-toolbar-scripts/) script I was using also is doing the same thing.

Thanks for reading.

Jannis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a script in AppleScript Editor and then save it as an Application, there is an option to show a `Startup Screen`, as shown in the image below:

[image]

When that option is enabled, when you launch the script in the Finder, it will first show that initial dialog before continuing.

As long as the AppleScript script-application in question wasn't saved with the `Run Only` option (see the image above), you should be able to open the script in AppleScript Editor by dragging the script-application's icon onto AppleScript Editor's icon. (When a script is saved as `Run Only`, AppleScript Editor won't allow you to open it to see the source code). So, if you are able to open it OK, then you could Save a copy of it and make sure the `Startup Screen` option is disabled.

As for why this suddenly started happening when yesterday it didn't, I'm not sure. What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: Hi, my OSX version is 10.6.6. I am able to open the script and resaved it. It works again now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old - but it happened to me today on macOS Sierra 10.12.4.

Based on [this page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2663278?tstart=0) I solved it be running `chmod +rw applet.rsrc` in the */Contents/Resources* folder under the applet.

Strangely enough, `ls -l` looks identical before and after `chmod +rw applet.rsrc`, but the prompt has stopped appearing.